# React native Cloudkit push notifications in android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

How to register for cloudkit push notifications in react-native android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the influence of react native is, but generally speaking CloudKit would function like this:

If you are using the webservice api, then you can only modify subscriptions. You can not register for a subscription. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you are using the javascript api, then you can also subscribe. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKitJS/Reference/CloudKitJSTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/struct/CloudKit.Subscription

I assume that the javascript subscription will only work as long as your application is active and your created subscription is active. I have no experience with this, so I could be wrong.